# Difference in differences placebo test plot

Tags: r, tidyverse, economics

How do I make graphs like [this](https://mixtape.scunning.com/graphics/unins.jpg) in R?

Lets say I have a dataset like this:

```
data <- tibble(date=sample(seq(as.Date("2006-01-01"), 
                                as.Date("2019-01-01"), by="day"),
                            10000, replace = T),
                treatment=sample(c(0,1),10000, replace= T),
                after=ifelse(date>as.Date("2015-03-01"), 1, 0),
                score=rnorm(10000)+ifelse(treatment*after==1, 0.2, 0)
)
```

and is doing a difference in differences analysis:

```
did <- lm(score~treatment+after+treatment*after, data=data)
summary(did)
```

How can I make a plot with placebo tests?

Answer (score 1):

Just using plot_model function in sjPlot.

```
data <- tibble(date=sample(seq(as.Date("2006-01-01"), 
                               as.Date("2019-01-01"), by="day"),
                           10000, replace = T),
               treatment=sample(c(0,1),10000, replace= T),
               after=ifelse(date>as.Date("2015-03-01"), 1, 0),
               score=rnorm(10000)+ifelse(treatment*after==1, 0.2, 0)
)

did <- lm(score~treatment+after+treatment*after, data=data)
summary(did)

sjPlot::plot_model(did,vline = 'black',show.values = T) + ylim(-.25, .5)
```

vline means to add a horizontal line at x = 1;

show.values means whether values should be plotted or not.

You can check the details of argument of plot_model from [here](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/reference/plot_model.html).

[image]

Comment: Expand your answer, add the plot, maybe link to the package, otherwise this answer could just be a comment.